# Como fazer uma função que pega dados e solta no chat do bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

Boa tarde eu tenho um bot pra um site onde frequento e queria desenvolver uma função onde ele manda um mensagem privada no sistema. 
Na minha cabeça parece simples porém não consigo executar (eu sei que o código está errado mas era assim que imaginava).

Sou novato na área de programação e queria ajuda de como resolver isso.

É bem simples, o usuário chamaria `/sms` para o bot e logo em seguida ele capturaria tudo o que tive-se na frente de `/sms`. Depois ele pegaria isso e jogaria no chat.

Seria um função de falar anonimamente, alguém pode me ajudar?

Sei que é uma pergunta boba mais tenho esta dúvida.

Desde já obrigado.

> (Edit) Eu consegui resolver o problema porém quando mando a mensagem ele reproduz o código também!

[image: Imagem]

```
#private mensagem
def mensagemprivate(self, message, name_sender, to=''):
        if re.findall('/sms .*', message):
            self.post(message=message)

elif '/sms' in message:
        t_mensagemprivate = threading.Thread(target=self.mensagemprivate, args=(message, name_sender, id_sender))
        t_mensagemprivate.start()
```

Comment: Não poste código como imagem; o site possuí suporte a código, basta fazer o [tour] para entender melhor.

Comment: Serio ninguém sabe me ajudar como consigo tirar esse /sms da frente .... ;~;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem duas maneiras de remover o texto `/sms` da sua mensagem.

Uma delas é usando a função `.replace`, que substitui um texto por outro. No seu caso, você pode substiruir por uma string vazia:

```
...
elif '/sms' in message:
    message = message.replace('/sms ', '')  # Substituindo o texto por vazio
...
```

Ou você pode partir a sua string na posição do texto que você quer remover:

```
...
elif '/sms' in message:
    message = message[5:]  # Isto "corta" a string e retorna a partir do quinto caractere até seu fim
...
```

Comment: Funciono cara Muito obrigado. usei o 2 exemplo